# Cakephp : Validate recaptcha

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1, recaptcha

I have downloaded a recaptchalib and successfully implemented the recaptcha and its displaying the recaptcha on my page but i am not able to validate it ... how can i validate the recaptcha

In View File

```
 <div id="recaptcha_div"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
  Recaptcha.create("<?php echo Configure::read("recatpch_settings.public_key")?>",   'recaptcha_div', {
  theme: "red",
  callback: Recaptcha.focus_response_field});
});

</script>
```

Controller's Login action

```
 public function login() {

    App::import('Vendor', 'recaptchalib', array('file' =>   'recaptchalib/recaptchalib.php'));
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (Configure::read("recatpch_settings.private_key"),
        $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
        $this->params['form']["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
        $this->params['form']["recaptcha_response_field"]);
    pr($resp);
    exit();
    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The reCAPTCHA wasn\'t entered correctly. Please, try again.');
    } else {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to validate the captcha. I want to login the user if i types the correct captcha and obviously username and password.

Comment: are you checking the code localhost? if so then the api will not work. api check the url with the api key. So if you sign up with a certain url and try to test it on other site then the api will not work.

If this is not the case, post the what is showing for pr($resp);

Answer (score 4):

I know that this is a very old question by now but I'll just go ahead and answer for those who might be looking into implementing this.

**Add the Site/Secret key to your app/config/bootstrap.php file.**

```
//Recaptcha Config
Configure::write('Recaptcha.SiteKey','YourSiteKey');
Configure::write('Recaptcha.SecretKey','YourSecretKey');
```

**Adding the reCaptcha widget to your view/form:**

```
<div>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" 
         data-sitekey="<?php echo Configure::read('Recaptcha.SiteKey'); ?>">
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->Html->script('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"'); ?>
</div>
```

**Verifying the user's response (reusable function inside your controller):**

```
private function __checkRecaptchaResponse($response){
    // verifying the response is done through a request to this URL
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    // The API request has three parameters (last one is optional)
    $data = array('secret' => Configure::read('Recaptcha.SecretKey'),
                    'response' => $response,
                    'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );

    // We could also use curl to send the API request
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $json_result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $result = json_decode($json_result);
    return $result->success;
}
```

**You check response by calling the above function after submitting a form containing the widget:**

```
if($this->__checkRecaptchaResponse($this->request->data['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    // user solved the captcha
} else {
    // user failed to solve the captcha
}
```

**Useful resources:**

- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display
- https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Answer (score 1):

Google has been introduced new reCaptcha API which is Are you a robot? A new design captcha system. This protects your website for robots and spammers, in this post I had implemented new reCaptch API system with HTML login form using CakePHP. Please take a look quick look at the demo.

**Get reCaptcha Key**

[Click here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html) to create a Google reCaptcha application.

**Register Your Website**

Give your website domain details without http:

[image]

**Google Site Key**

You will use this in HTML code.

[image]

**Google Secret Key**

This will help your website to communication with Google.

[image]

**HTML code**

Contains HTML code with Google reCaptcha snippet. You have to modify the GOOGLE_SITE_KEY value.

```
<html>
<head>
/* Google reCaptcha JS */
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<label>Username</label>
<?php echo $this->Form->text('User.username', array('maxlength' => 32))?>
<label>Password</label>
<?php echo $this->Form->password('User.password', array('maxlength' => 32))?>
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="GOOGLE_SITE_KEY"></div>
<input type="submit"  value="Log In" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Create new Vendor in Vendor file:

**curl.php**

```
<?php
function getCurlData($url)
{
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16");
$curlData = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $curlData;
}
?>
```

Using in controller, You have to modify the GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY value.

```
$recaptcha = $this->data['g-recaptcha-response'];

$google_url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
$secret = 'GOOGLE_SECRET_KEY';
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$url = $google_url . "?secret=" . $secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha ."&remoteip=" . $ip;
App::import('Vendor', 'curl');
$res = getCurlData($url);
$res = json_decode($res, true);

if(empty($res['success'])){

//if success not empty
//some code here
}
```

Hope it's useful.